# SecurityException - Erro de Permissão

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Olá, estou subindo uma aplicação em minha hospedagem Locaweb e fiquei parado neste erro, alguém sabe como resolver este problema de permissão ?

```
[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) +0
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(CodeAccessPermission cap, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +31
   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() +48
   System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.InitializeImpl() +1093
   System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.Initialize() +29
   System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter..ctor(String categoryName, String counterName, String instanceName, Boolean readOnly) +128
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.PerformanceCounterManager.LoadCounter(String categoryName, String counterName, String instanceName, Boolean isReadOnly) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.PerformanceCounterManager.SetCounterProperties(String instanceName) +88
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.PerformanceCounterManager.Initialize(String instanceName, CancellationToken hostShutdownToken) +121
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hosting.HostDependencyResolverExtensions.InitializePerformanceCounters(IDependencyResolver resolver, String instanceName, CancellationToken hostShutdownToken) +35
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hosting.HostDependencyResolverExtensions.InitializeHost(IDependencyResolver resolver, String instanceName, CancellationToken hostShutdownToken) +38
   Owin.OwinExtensions.UseType(IAppBuilder builder, Object[] args) +121
   Owin.OwinExtensions.MapHubs(IAppBuilder builder, String path, HubConfiguration configuration) +72
   System.Web.Routing.<>c__DisplayClassc.<MapHubs>b__a(IAppBuilder map) +38
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinAppContext.Initialize(Action`1 startup) +397
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.Build(Action`1 startup) +46
   System.Web.Routing.RouteCollectionExtensions.MapOwinPath(RouteCollection routes, String name, String pathBase, Action`1 startup) +40
   System.Web.Routing.SignalRRouteExtensions.MapHubs(RouteCollection routes, String name, String path, HubConfiguration configuration, Action`1 build) +267
   System.Web.Routing.SignalRRouteExtensions.MapHubs(RouteCollection routes, String path, HubConfiguration configuration) +117
   System.Web.Routing.SignalRRouteExtensions.MapHubs(RouteCollection routes, HubConfiguration configuration) +12
   System.Web.Routing.SignalRRouteExtensions.MapHubs(RouteCollection routes) +36
   UI.Web.MvcApplication.Application_Start() +15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daniel,

Aparentemente é um erro de nível de acesso do servidor IIS:

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1626

http://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Security_Level_de_servidores_Windows_em_ambiente_compartilhado

Na locaweb o Security Level é sempre "Medium Trust".

Sua aplicação requer "Full Trust"? Se não, talvez seja o caso de ajustar isso.

Comment: Realmente, vou ter que trocar de hospedagem. Obrigado

Comment: Qual hospedagem você encontrou que suporta Full Trust?